# Postgres Minimum of two overlaps in array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I need to search a large table (over 100million records) using quite a complex set of rules.

At present I have a table that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE equipment (
     id serial primary key,
     description varchar,
     code integer,
     tags varchar[]
)
```

And I need to query based on

1) A specific list of codes (WHERE code IN (1,4,5,8)

2) An array of tags that are NOT in the tags array

3) An array of tags that are IN the tags array but at least two need to be present

```
SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE 
    code IN (1,3,6,7,8) 
    AND NOT ('{sports, outdoors, camping}' && tags)
    AND ('{tennis, squash, badminton, volleyball}' && tags)
```

But I do not know how to make that at least two of the values (tennis, squash, badminton, volleyball) overlap the tags array.

I am using Postgres 10.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only do that using by unnesting the tags and counting them:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM equipment e
WHERE code IN (1,3,6,7,8) 
  AND NOT ('{sports, outdoors, camping}' && tags)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM unnest(e.tags) x(tg)
              WHERE x.tg = any ('{tennis, squash, badminton, volleyball}')
              HAVING count(*) >= 2);
```

---

If you have an index on the `tags` column then AND ('{tennis, squash, badminton, volleyball}' && tags) keeping your current condition:

```
AND ('{tennis, squash, badminton, volleyball}' && tags)
```

might improve the performance, as that should prevent unnesting the tags for rows where no match was found to begin with.

Comment: Awesome, thanks v much. And yes i did have a GIN index on the tags so that extra AND helped